# Disable add to cart button before modal confirmation is shown in prestashop 1.7

Tags: modal-dialog, prestashop, addition, cart

On my prestashop 1.7.6.8 I am noticing a very slow timing to add the product to the cart and then to show the modal popup of confirmation.
Is it possible to avoid users click on button during this latency?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I done it like that:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function(){
  $( '.add-to-cart' ).addClass("sending");
});
$(document).ajaxStop(function(){
  $( '.add-to-cart' ).removeClass("sending");
});
```